# Dynamic spinner using a SQLite Database

Tags: sql, database, spinner

I want my spinner to be dynamically updated from my SQLite database. The spinner should contain months and years (ex. april 2013), from my sqlite database.
I have searched the web a lot, and also many of the questions from this site, but now i can't solve the rest.
Right now my spinner list is getting longer, but there is no text? What is the problem?

Here is the relevant code in my main class

```
KilometerSQL info = new KilometerSQL(this);
    info.open();
    String data = info.getData();
    final Cursor cSpinner;
    cSpinner = (Cursor) KilometerSQL.getSpinnerData();
    startManagingCursor(cSpinner);

    SimpleCursorAdapter scaYear = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,     android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,cSpinner,new String[] {KilometerSQL.KEY_MONTH},new int[]{});
    scaYear.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(scaYear);
    info.close();
    tvView.setText(data);
```

And here is my SQLiteDatabase:

```
public static Cursor getSpinnerData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                return ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, //table name
                new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_MONTH}, //list of columns to return
                null, //filter declaring which rows to return; formatted as SQL WHERE clause
                null,
                KEY_MONTH, //filter declaring how to group rows; formatted as SQL GROUP BY clause
                null, //filter declaring which row groups to include in cursor; formatted as SQL HAVING clause
                null); //how to order rows; formatted as SQL ORDER BY clause
    }
```

Don't hesitate to ask questions if you need some info or code.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution..

I needed to add this into the code: android.R.id.text1

like this:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter scaYear = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,cSpinner,new String[] {KilometerSQL.KEY_MONTH},new int[]{android.R.id.text1});
```